# Representing Either in pureconfig

Tags: scala, config, either, hocon, pureconfig

I have a HOCON config like this:

```
[
    {
        name = 1
        url = "http://example.com"
    },
    {
        name = 2
        url = "http://example2.com"
    },
    {
        name = 3
        url = {
            A = "http://example3.com"
            B = "http://example4.com"
        }
    }
]
```

I want to parse it with pureconfig.
How can I represent that the URL can be either a string or a map of multiple urls, each having a key?

I have tried this:

```
import pureconfig.ConfigSource
import pureconfig.generic.auto.exportReader

case class Site(name: Int, url: Either[String, Map[String, String]])
case class Config(sites: List[Site])
ConfigSource.default.loadOrThrow[Config]
```

But it resulted in "Expected type OBJECT. Found STRING instead."

I know pureconfig supports `Option`. I have found no mention of supporting `Either`, does it mean it can be replaced with something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see `Either` in not on list of [types supported out of the box](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/built-in-supported-types.html).

However `Either` falls under [sealed family](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/overriding-behavior-for-sealed-families.html), so:

```
@ ConfigSource.string("""{ type: left, value: "test" }""").load[Either[String, String]]
res15: ConfigReader.Result[Either[String, String]] = Right(Left("test"))

@ ConfigSource.string("""{ type: right, value: "test" }""").load[Either[String, String]]
res16: ConfigReader.Result[Either[String, String]] = Right(Right("test"))
```

works. If you have a sealed hierarchy, what pureconfig will do is require an object which has a field `type` - this field will be used to dispatch parsing to a specific subtype. All the other fields will be passed as fields to parse into that subtype.

If that doesn't work for you, you might try to implement the codec yourself:

```
// just an example
implicit def eitherReader[A: ConfigReader, B: ConfigReader] =
  new ConfigReader[Either[A, B]] {
    def from(cur: ConfigCursor) =
      // try left, if fail try right
      ConfigReader[A].from(cur).map(Left(_)) orElse ConfigReader[B].from(cur).map(Right(_))
  }
```

which now will not require discrimination value:

```
@ ConfigSource.string("""{ test: "test" }""").load[Map[String, Either[String, String]]]
res26: ConfigReader.Result[Map[String, Either[String, String]]] = Right(Map("test" -> Left("test")))
```

This is not provided by default because you would have to answer a few things yourself:

- how do you decide if you should go with `Left` or `Right` decoding?
- does `Left` fallback `Right` or `Right` fallback `Left` make sense?
- how about `Either[X, X]`?

If you have an idea what is expected behavior you can implement your own codec and use it in derivation.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, this answer showed me the way. Especially the custom `ConfigReader` with `orElse` part.

Comment: Maybe union types in scala 3 will answer these questions in general

Comment: I get " value orElse is not a member of scala.util.Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures,scala.util.Left[A,Nothing]]" with this variant. am I missing an import or something similar?

Comment: It's available since 2.13 https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html#orElse[A1%3E:A,B1%3E:B](or:=%3Escala.util.Either[A1,B1]):scala.util.Either[A1,B1]

Answer (score 1):

There are might be several ways of doing it, but I don't like using Either as a config representation. Thus, I would suggest to use ADT approach with sealed trait:

```
  sealed trait NameUrl {
    val name: Int
  }

  case class Name(
    name: Int,
    url: String
  ) extends NameUrl

  case class NameUrlObj(
    name: Int,
    url: Map[String, String]
  ) extends NameUrl
```

Sorry for my naming here. This would be a representation of of your config.
We need to modify a bit our config to parse easily the config with you ADT. In order to support generic types you should add your spefici type name for each subtype.
I'm going to put here full example so that you can run it on your machine:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import pureconfig.generic.auto._
import pureconfig.ConfigSource

object TstObj extends App {

  sealed trait NameUrl {
    val name: Int
  }

  case class Name(
    name: Int,
    url: String
  ) extends NameUrl

  case class NameUrlObj(
    name: Int,
    url: Map[String, String]
  ) extends NameUrl

  val cfgStr = ConfigFactory.parseString(
    """
      |abc: [
      |  {
      |    type: name,
      |    name = 1
      |    url = "http://example.com"
      |  },
      |  {
      |    type: name,
      |    name = 1
      |    url = "http://example.com"
      |  },
      |  {
      |    type: name-url-obj,
      |    name = 3
      |    url = {
      |      "A": "http://example3.com"
      |      "B": "http://example4.com"
      |    }
      |  }
      |]
      |""".stripMargin
  )


  case class RootA(abc: List[NameUrl])
  println(ConfigSource.fromConfig(cfgStr).loadOrThrow[RootA])

}
```

You can read more here about [Sealed Families here](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/overriding-behavior-for-sealed-families.html)

Comment: Yeah, this is a good solution, but the config needs to have `type` (or `kind` or some other key) which seems redundant

Comment: Yes, it's up to you which way is better for you. IMHO, Either cannot/shouldn't be a representation of static data.